# How to send single key (e.g. 'k') to window in Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, key

I'm writing some automated tests for website that mostly uses keyboard shortcuts for navigation. Some of them are with special keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and with those I have no problem.

But when I try to send single letters or num-pad symbols, it's not working. When I try to send it to non-text field or root element, it returns exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

I also tried Actions, but they are designed for special (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>) key combination.

I'm working with Java Selenium Web-driver for Chrome.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you will send single key then selenium will consider it is as text rather than shortcut key..

Comment: Yes, you right. But, my client has such shortcuts in his application and no way of changing it (legacy). Is there anything that can be done to test them?

Comment: can you please share code which is working fine with firefox but not with chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Chrome Driver has some issues with sending keys to non-text fields.

I changed ChromeDriver to FirefoxDriver and it's working now. Cannot figure how make it work for Chrome, though.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
```

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("..enter your xpath..")).sendKeys(Keys.K);`